# Unable to put a div or article element inside an anchor

Tags: html, anchor

Putting block elements inside an anchor is now "possible" or allowed in HTML5, but it does not work for some reason.
Here's the code:

```
<a href="#"><div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="prodimg/senseo-m.jpg"/>
                </figure>
                <div class="proddetail">
                    <header>
                        <hgroup>
                            <h2>Koffiepadsysteem</h2>
                            <h1>Senseo</h1>
                        </hgroup>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </header>
                    <span class="price">&euro; 79,99</span>
                    <span class="elders">elders &euro; 89,99</span>
                    <span class="bespaart">u bespaart &euro; 15%</span>
                    <a href="#"><span class="meerinfo">Meer info</span></a>
                </div>
            </div></a>
```

When I inspect the code in firefox or chrome, I get this result:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<div><a href="#">
                <figure>
                    <img src="prodimg/senseo-m.jpg">
                </figure>
                </a><div class="proddetail"><a href="#">
                    <header>
                        <hgroup>
                            <h2>Koffiepadsysteem</h2>
                            <h1>Senseo</h1>
                        </hgroup>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </header>
                    <span class="price">€ 79,99</span>
                    <span class="elders">elders € 89,99</span>
                    <span class="bespaart">u bespaart € 15%</span>
                    </a><a href="#"><span class="meerinfo">Meer info</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

That's almost good, but certain spots still aren't clickable. Any idea when can be done here?

Comment: Have you tried setting `display:block` on the anchor tag?

Comment: I'm already using the html doctype, and turning the anchor into a block does the same :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem found!

Wrapping a block element in an anchor IS possible, but you can't put *another* anchor in there, too. Then it breaks.

So the parent anchor can't contain a child anchor.